# MySQL Database Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2015/06/08' for function str_to_date

Tags: mysql, datetime, str-to-date

I'm trying to insert a date from a string in another table.  The *SELECT* statement provides no error while the *INSERT* statement provides the error "*Incorrect datetime value: '2015/06/08' for function str_to_date*"
The data in the *1CON* field is *2015/06/08*

```
INSERT INTO dest
SELECT COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(1CON, '%m/%d/%Y'),
STR_TO_DATE(1CON, '%Y/%m/%d')) 
FROM origin WHERE REC=4953;
```

And the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(1CON, '%m/%d/%Y'),
STR_TO_DATE(1CON, '%Y/%m/%d'))
FROM origin WHERE REC=4953;
```

Comment: I'm unsure about the syntax, but it seems weird to pass `2015/06/08` and `%m/%d/%Y` (month = 2015, day = 06, year = 08) in the same command. Did you mean `%Y/%m/%d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert dates as `'2015-06-02'` kinda format

insert datetimes as `'2015-06-02 14:02:28'`

yes, for June 2